# Having issues enabling short_open_tag for PHP

Tags: php

First, yes I know I shouldn't use short tags, but they are all through the project I'm currently working on, and I just need it to work.

I have enabled `short_open_tag` in `/etc/php.ini` and restarted Apache. When I run `phpinfo()` I see that it is enabled, however when I run my project, the short tags don't work. I've done some searching, but haven't found any answers. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Since `short_open_tag` config value can be changed anywhere (even from PHP code itself), it is possible that your project explicitly disables them via `ini_set()`; 2) your site for this project may be configured to use different php.ini (this is unlikely to happen as I expect that you run your `phpinfo()` test on the same site as project).

Comment: 1) I grepped the project for `ini_set` and had no luck finding anything, and 2) yeah, I ran `phpinfo()` from inside the project.

Comment: Where do you use them (what file extension)? Does full tag works in that file? Otherwise no ideas.

Comment: They are being used in .php files, full tags are working. I have run this project successfully before. I just switched from Ubuntu to Fedora, and that's when the problem started.

Comment: string replace `<?` with `<?php` this will eliminate the need to require short_open_tag to be turned on in the server configuration.  This will make your code potable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string replace `<?` with `<?php` this will eliminate the need to require `short_open_tag` to be turned on in the server configuration.  This will make your code portable.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration (if it's `mod_php`, not CGI) may be also changed in the `.htaccess` files with a `php_flag` setting. Look there.